# How do I restore a deleted tag?

Tags: tags

In attempting to remove a tag from a contact, i succeeded in deleting the whole tag for everyone. Is there a simple way to restore it?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not.  Hopefully you have a backup of your database, and ideally a test site?  If you load the backup on your test site, you should be able to search for people with the tag, select **Export**, and export only the Contact ID.  Import the Contact ID list to your live site, and on the last page of the import, select **Create a New Tag**.  You can enter the tag's name there.  The import won't do anything other than create the tag, since it's only contact IDs.